# Access Denied: 403 Error for Storage Symbolic Link

Tags: laravel, apache, http-status-code-403

I have an issue with the server not being able to access files. Here are the relevant addresses:

This is Error :

> Forbidden
> You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Main address:
/home/admin/domains/{mydomain.com}

Source address:
/home/admin/domains/{mydomain.com}/source

Symblink address:
/home/admin/domains/{mydomain.com}/public_html/storage

Storage symlink:
/home/admin/domains/{mydomain.com}/source/storage/app/public

When I save a file in Laravel, it works fine. However, when I try to access the file through the website, I receive a 403 error.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel , Apache .

```
ln -s /home/admin/domains/{domain.com}/{whne source files}/storage/app/public/  /home/admin/domains/{domain.com}/public_html/storage
```